# Im trying to switch Parameters around in Python without making globals

Tags: python-3.x

How do I get these variables back into the main function? (This is apart of class and I can't use Global for it. Also I must have the print apart of the main function. Getting Errors like AssessedTotalValue not assigned and PropertyTaxTotal not assigned. It worked for getting the Parameter variable into the function but why arn't they coming out of them?

```
def PropertyTax():
    global PropertyTaxPercent
    PropertyTaxPercent = .64
    PropertyValue = int(input( "Enter Property Value: "))
    AssessedValue(PropertyValue)
    PropertyTaxValue(AssessedTotalValue)
    print ("The Property Assessed Value is: ", AssessedTotalValue)
    print ("The Property Tax is: ", PropertyTaxTotal)

def AssessedValue(PropertyValue):
    global AssessedPercentValue
    AssessedPercentValue = 0.60
    AssessedTotalValue = PropertyValue * AssessedPercentValue

def PropertyTaxValue(AssessedTotalValue):
    PropertyTaxValue = AssessedTotalValue / 100
    PropertyTaxTotal = PropertyTaxValue * PropertyTaxPercent
PropertyTax()
```

Comment: You've learned about arguments. Now look up "return values".

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to define your variables as global. 
You can use return statements in your functions that will make your functions give back values to where you called the function from.

eg.

```
def add(a,b):
    total = a + b
    return total
```

sum = add(1,6)
print(sum)

Would output 7.

---

Given this you can amend your program to the following:

```
def PropertyTax():

    PropertyTaxPercent = .64
    PropertyValue = int(input( "Enter Property Value: "))
    AssessedTotalValue = AssessedValue(PropertyValue)
    PropertyTaxTotal = PropertyTaxValue(AssessedTotalValue,PropertyTaxPercent)
    print ("The Property Assessed Value is: ", AssessedTotalValue)
    print ("The Property Tax is: ", PropertyTaxTotal)

def AssessedValue(PropertyValue):
    AssessedPercentValue = 0.60
    AssessedTotalValue = PropertyValue * AssessedPercentValue
    return AssessedTotalValue

def PropertyTaxValue(AssessedTotalValue,PropertyTaxPercent):
    PropertyTaxValue = AssessedTotalValue / 100
    PropertyTaxTotal = PropertyTaxValue * PropertyTaxPercent
    return PropertyTaxTotal

PropertyTax()
```